# access <li data-value = "2"> with jquery and css design change with jquery

Tags: jquery

access `<li data-value = "2">` with jquery and css design change

```
<ul>
<li data-value = "2"> white </ li>
<li data-value = "1"> gray background </ li>
<li data-value = "1"> gray background </ li>
<li data-value = "1"> gray background </ li>
</ ul>
```

Someone can help me, as I can do it with jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use CSS attribute-selectors for this:

```
/* retrieves those <li> elements, with the 'data-value' attribute
   equal to "1": */
li[data-value="1"] {
  background-color: #fff;
}
li[data-value="2"] {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background-color: #0af;
}

li {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

li[data-value="2"] {
  background-color: #fff;
}

li[data-value="1"] {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li data-value="2">white</li>
  <li data-value="1">gray background</li>
  <li data-value="1">gray background</li>
  <li data-value="1">gray background</li>
</ul>
```

Alternatively, using JavaScript:

```
// get a NodeList of the relevant elements:
var dataValueElems = document.querySelectorAll('li[data-value="1"],li[data-value="2"]'),
// a simple map of the data-value to the desired colour:
    valueToColor = {
      '1' : '#ccc',
      '2' : '#fff'
    };

// iterating over the array-like NodeList, using
// Array.prototype.forEach:
Array.prototype.forEach.call(dataValueElems, function (li) {
  // if there is a colour associated with the data-value
  // attribute-value we set that colour as the background-color,
  // otherwise we use an empty string (which effectively sets no colour):
  li.style.backgroundColor = valueToColor[li.dataset.value] || '';
});
```

```js
var dataValueElems = document.querySelectorAll('li[data-value="1"],li[data-value="2"]'),
    valueToColor = {
      '1' : '#ccc',
      '2' : '#fff'
    };

Array.prototype.forEach.call(dataValueElems, function (li) {
  li.style.backgroundColor = valueToColor[li.dataset.value] || '';
});
```

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background-color: #0af;
}

li {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li data-value="2">white</li>
  <li data-value="1">gray background</li>
  <li data-value="1">gray background</li>
  <li data-value="1">gray background</li>
</ul>
```

References:

- CSS:

  - [Attribute (`[attribute="value"]`) selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors).
- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll).
  - [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
  - [`HTMLElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.dataset).
  - [`HTMLElement.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style).

Answer (score 0):

js code look like this,

```
$('li').each(function(){
  //alert($(this).data('value'));
    var v = $(this).data('value');
    if (v == '2'){
        $(this).css('background-color', '#f00');
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/28phsy2L/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Use attribute selector

```
$('li[data-value=2]').css('color','red');
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bshkhmz4/)**</kbd>